# Standard directory for moduls downloaded via pip isn't in sys.path

Tags: python, pip, path, sys

Moduls like requests are downloaded in the folder C:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\package\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
(or at least that is the directory listed under location when I use pip show on requests or any other module)Which isn't a folder listed in sys.path. I can't use them as a result. I'm pretty sure that I've never changed the pip download directory or the directorys in path.

I need some way to either add the folder to sys.path or change the pip download folder so that I can redownload them in a directory that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you messed up your installation you could simply add the "download-path" via

```
sys.path.append(download-path)
```

Comment: yeah but you have to do that every time, I was looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: Then do a complete reinstall and consider using virtual environments like a pro.